# Camel client acknowledge mode is not working

Tags: apache-camel, jms

I'm creating a Spring Boot application using Apache Camel to connect to ActiveMQ and IBM MQ. I'm using the JMS component to connect the MQ. I'm using the acknowledgement as `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` so any exception or application crash message should retain in MQ. But when I start the application and as soon as the message received in MQ it's getting cleared. Below is my configuration

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate" id="jmsTemplate">
   <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
   <property name="receiveTimeout" value="1000" />
</bean>
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
   <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
   <property name="cacheConsumers" value="true" />
   <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true" />
   <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="100"/>
</bean>
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
   <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
</bean>
<bean id="config" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
   <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
   <property name="transacted" value="true"/>
   <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_CONSUMER"/>
   <property name="acknowledgementModeName" value="CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE"/>    
</bean>
<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
   <property name="configuration" ref="config" />
</bean>
```

Please help me what's need to be added to achieve the functionality.

Comment: The code above is not using client ack, but transacted ack mode, eg transacted=true. And in general its better to use TX mode for automatic rollback. See for example the transaction chapter in the CiA2 book.

Comment: Thanks.. but my requirements is if I read a msg from MQ I should acknowledge after the process success. So in between if the application goes down the message remain in the mq. If change the transacted value to false whether it will work as client acknowledge behavior.

Comment: I have made the transacted = false and added consumer type to default in jms configuration, so it will use deafultMessageListenercontainer. Still no use.. am I missing anything

Comment: i was able to solve by adding these properties in JMS Template,
<bean class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate" id="jmsTemplate">
   <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
   <property name="receiveTimeout" value="1000" />
   <property name="sessionAcknowledgeModeName" value="CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE"/>
  <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>
</bean>